# vertex ai pipeline custom job 'Internal error occurred'

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

when running a custom job in vertex ai I encountered this error. [error screenshoot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u464u.png)

but when I run my training on vertex workbench with same machine specification on my pipeline component it works fine.

I try to run a training pipeline in vertex ai

[here's the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjarD.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you click on the "view log" button as per your screenshot, it may give you some clue about which step failed. If you have data on your logs and if you are open to share it (removing any personal/confidential information before sharing) it may help to assist you

Answer (score 1):

Encountering the "Internal error occurred" message while trying to run a custom training job on Vertex AI, even though the same job runs smoothly on Vertex Workbench with identical machine specifications, can be addressed through these troubleshooting steps:

1. Ensure the configuration of the pipeline component in the Vertex AI pipeline mirrors that of Vertex Workbench. This encompasses aspects like machine specs, input paths, environment settings, and other relevant details.
2. Confirm the accuracy of data and dependencies specified within the pipeline component. Mistakes or missing data paths can trigger problems.
3. Verify that the pipeline component has proper permissions and isn't encountering network issues.
4. Test the job using different environments or base images.

Remember, resolving internal errors can be intricate. If problems persist, contacting Vertex AI or Google Cloud Platform support is advisable for specialized help.